# Supending on the autohotkey script when the right Shift is hold down

Tags: debugging, autohotkey

I would to change the behavior of the RShift (Right Shift) with the following requirements:

- to suspend on the autohotkey script when the RShift is hold down,
- to suspend off the script it when the RShift is released,
- to preserve the original capitalizing behavior of the RShift (e.g., by holding down RShift then pressing t gives T).

So far I have the following code, but unfortunately it does not preserve the original function of the right Shift.

```
$RShift::
Suspend On
Send {LShift down}
KeyWait, Rshift
Suspend Off
Send {LShift up}
return
```

Comment: Try adding [#InstallKeybdHook](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InstallKeybdHook.htm) to the auto-execute section.

Comment: @user3419297 Would it possible to elaborate more regarding the particular situation of my question? If you have a solution feel free to post it.

Comment: Your code works on my system if I add `#InstallKeybdHook` on top. Try it as a stand alone script.

Comment: @user3419297 great thanks.